# Find a differential operator s.t a specific function is a Green function

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:x\mapsto\log\sinh(|x|)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^*_+$,
Is it possible to find a differential operator $\mathcal{D}$ such that $\mathcal{D}(f)=\delta_0$, *ie* $f$ is the Green function of the operator $\mathcal{D}$ ?

Comment: The $\log$ function does occur as the Green's function in the context of the 2D Laplace operator. So one may be able to start from that and transform it into the desired $\log \sinh |x|$ form.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try things but my main issue is that my problem is defined in 1D while log is the 2D-Laplacian Green function